# Alloy , nl.fokkezb.loading giving error on show function. I need to upgrade some old apk, when I rebuild the old code getting this issue

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

My current Ti SDK is 9.2.0.GA, and ti cli is 5.2.5. I need to upgrade an old application that was built with 3.2.0.GA. I changed the tiapp.xml file and updated the SDK version to 9.2.0.GA. Then I am getting this error. Please help me to resolve the issue.

```
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1736,2805] /alloy/widgets/nl.fokkezb.loading/controllers/window.js:151
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler: $.loadingIndicator.show();
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:                    ^
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler: Error: Unable to convert null
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     at Controller.open (/alloy/widgets/nl.fokkezb.loading/controllers/window.js:151:20)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     at Controller.show (/alloy/widgets/nl.fokkezb.loading/controllers/widget.js:67:9)
```

Comment: going from 9.2 to 3.4 probably introduces MANY breaking changes, you might need to rebuild your entire app. SDK 3.4 is over 6 years old, in software that is ancient history.

Comment: +1 for rebuilding the app! Since nl.fokkezb.loading is a widget you can remove that and use the normal `ActivityIndicator` for example. It can be used as a normal View in both OS and you can create a Widget yourself to use it. Remove it just to see other errors that occur. Happy to hear if you can raise the SDK to the latest!

Comment: Sorry, my question was written badly.

Comment: you could also add a null check around line 151 in the loading widget

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error by installing gitTio globally and then Installing missing (versions of) modules and widgets required in tiapp.xml.

```
//Install gittio globaly
[sudo] npm install -g gittio 
//navigate to project directory and run this command
~/myproject $ gittio install -g
```